# why it not navigate to the dashboard page after login

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-directive

````
id: any;
loginsubmit(id: any) {
console.log("button works");
const che = \[\];
this.admincreation.getdatas(id).subscribe((che: any) =\> {
{
const adminl = che.find((b: any) =\> {
return b.loginemail === this.Login.value.loginemail && b.loginpassword  ===this.Login.value.loginpassword; 
});
if (adminl) {
Swal.fire('success', 'Admin is logged in successfully', 'succes`your text`s');
this.Login.reset();`your text`
this.route.navigate(\['/superadmin'\]);
} else {           
// user login logic
this.userLogin(id);         
}       
}});   
}  
userLogin(id: any) {
this.sign.getlogin(id).subscribe((res: any) =\> {
{
const user = res.find((b: any) =\> {
return b.loginemail === this.Login.value.loginemail && b.loginpassword === this.Login.value.loginpassword;
});
if (user){
Swal.fire({
icon:'success',
title:'SuccessFully',``` your text``your text ```
text:'Login Successfully',
});
this.route.navigate(\['/generalusers'\]);
this.dialog.open(UseraccesdelogComponent, {
width:'800px',
height:'600px',
});
this.Login.reset(); 
}
}
});
}
getlogin(id:any){
return this.http.get(this.urls,id); 
}
getdatas(id:any){
return this.http.get(this.urls,id);
}
````

why it not navigate to the next page after login it always shows che is not a function and in network it 200 ok but it not navigate to the next page
and using firebase a database to store all datas

Answer (score 0):

The error message `che` is not a function" suggests that there is an issue with the variable `che` being used as a function. Based on the code you provided, it appears that `che` is used both as an array and a function parameter, which could be causing the error.

```
id: any;

loginsubmit(id: any) {
 console.log("button works");
 const che = [];

 this.admincreation.getdatas(id).subscribe((data: any) => {
 // Remove the redundant curly braces here
 const adminl = data.find((b: any) => {
  return b.loginemail === this.Login.value.loginemail && b.loginpassword 
 === this.Login.value.loginpassword;
  });

  if (adminl) {
  Swal.fire('success', 'Admin is logged in successfully', 'success'); // Fixed the Swal.fire line
  this.Login.reset();
  this.route.navigate(['/superadmin']);
} else {
  // user login logic
  this.userLogin(id);
}
});
}

userLogin(id: any) {
this.sign.getlogin(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
const user = res.find((b: any) => {
  return b.loginemail === this.Login.value.loginemail && b.loginpassword === this.Login.value.loginpassword;
});

if (user) {
  Swal.fire({
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Successfully Logged In',
    text: 'Login Successfully',
  });
  this.route.navigate(['/generalusers']);
  this.dialog.open(UseraccesdelogComponent, {
    width: '800px',
    height: '600px',
  });
  this.Login.reset();
  }
  });
 }

 getlogin(id: any) {
  return this.http.get(this.urls, id);
 }

 getdatas(id: any) {
 return this.http.get(this.urls, id);
}
```

I've removed the extra curly braces, fixed the `Swal.fire` line, and adjusted some comments in your code. Ensure that your code is structured as shown above, and it should navigate to the next page after login correctly.

@priyasingh if you have please ask.